# DNS Name resolution problems

Tags: networking, server, 15.04, dns, display-resolution

When I try to initiate PayPal API hook, I got timeout error.
While trying over terminal, I found problems these:

Web API Request returns:

```
Connection timed out after 10365 milliseconds
```

`traceroute https://api.sandbox.paypal.com` returns:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

`ping https://api.sandbox.paypal.com` returns:

```
ping: unknown host https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
```

NB: I have working Internet connection, tried using 3 different ISP, PayPal.com opens fine and am not using any proxies or DNS Services. Even tried turning off network and back..

What could be denying my request? Why the domain doesn't resolve? Please advice..

Comment: Remove `https://` when using ping or traceroute. These tools work on *domain names* (and IP addresses), not on *URLs*.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are specifying a TCP port specification (`https://`) where commands are expecting a host name. `ping` uses the ICMP protocol, not TCP. For example:

```
$ ping -c 3 http://slashdot.org
ping: unknown host http://slashdot.org
$ ping -c 3 slashdot.org
PING slashdot.org (216.34.181.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from slashdot.org (216.34.181.45): icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=32.6 ms
64 bytes from slashdot.org (216.34.181.45): icmp_seq=2 ttl=242 time=33.2 ms
64 bytes from slashdot.org (216.34.181.45): icmp_seq=3 ttl=242 time=33.8 ms

--- slashdot.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.633/33.260/33.880/0.530 ms
```